# Equivalent of Tomcat Lifecycle Listener in JBoss 7?

Tags: tomcat, jboss, jboss7.x

I have an application running on Tomcat 7 which uses a LifeCycle listener in server.xml. I'd like to know if there's an equivalent in JBoss 7, because I'm thinking to port my applications on this platform.
Thanks
Mark

Comment: http://docs.jboss.org/mod_cluster/1.2.0/html/java.config.html#d0e1056 It totally depends on what you're actually doing, but this is some great info.

Answer (score 1):

I've found also another alternative, registering an MXBean which can be used in JBoss AS 7. 
More information on @MXBean annotation can be found in the following link:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/management/MXBean.html